# Disabling Javascript Code on Mobile (maybe touchscreen)?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, mobile

I've seen topics on disabling javascript for mobile but it's a little over my head. I know just enough to be dangerous. I have a hover effect for captions on photos using a script but on a mobile I've set the css so that it displays by default. Only problem is when you click the image to view a lightbox it tries to fire the hover effect. How do I disable that?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.fade').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).find('.caption').fadeIn(250);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).find('.caption').fadeOut(250);
    }
);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable (without much effort or danger) that particular behaviour for touch devices checking the  existence of the 'ontouchstart' property on the window object like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (!('ontouchstart' in window)) {
        $('.fade').hover(
            function(){
                $(this).find('.caption').fadeIn(250);
            },
            function(){
                $(this).find('.caption').fadeOut(250);
            }
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Forgive me for my ignorance but what am I missing?

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
 $('.fade').hover(
  function(){
   if ('ontouchstart' in window) {
    return false;
   }
   else {
   $(this).find('.caption').fadeIn(250);
  },
  function(){
   $(this).find('.caption').fadeOut(250);
  }
 );
    });
    </script>

Comment: Just changed the code in my answer.. moved the 'if' condition before binding the callbacks to the hover method, you should be fine now :)

Comment: You're a lifesaver man. Thanks. Someone upvote him please. I'm not allowed to.